# Let $A $ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le\operatorname{rank}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Tried using the fact that $\operatorname{col}(AB)\subseteq\operatorname{col}(A)$ but couldn't find the link.

Comment: One of the equivalent definitions for $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ is $\mathrm{dim} \,\,\mathrm{col}(A)$. Can you see the relation?

Comment: How do you define the rank?

Answer (score 0):

We will use the following notation:

For matrix $T\in F^{n\times n}$, we have $L_T: F^{n\times 1} \to F^{n\times 1}$ is the linear transformation defined by
$$ v \mapsto Tv $$

Now note that $\text{Im } L_{AB} = \text{Im } (L_A \restriction_{\text{Im} B})$. Thus the image of $L_{AB}$ is a subset of the image of $L_{A}$. Hence $\text{rank} (AB) \le \text{rank}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

We'll think the matrices as endomorphism of the space $V$. And so we'll think the product of $AB$ as composition of endomorphism.
$$V\underset{A}{\longrightarrow}V\underset{B}{\longrightarrow}V$$ 
First of all we have to note that linearity of A and B implies that the image of the vector $0$ is always $0$ and so we have the following relation on the kernel:
$$ker(AB)\supseteq ker(A)$$
Then the rank relation follows from the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: This is $\ker(BA)\supseteq\ker(A)$.

Comment: depends on the definitions he used which I'm not sure... I tried to make sense of his notation

Comment: As far as I know, the most common convention is that vectors are columns, written on the right. So your composition is $BA$, not $AB$. Some authors use row vectors, written on the left, though. But, since the OP states $\operatorname{col}(AB)\subseteq\operatorname{col}(A)$, the composition is in the first sense.

Comment: Indeed, as I said I tried to make sense of his title